# What is Algebra 1 "Number and quantity; Interpreting Data"?

Tags: algebra

My sister received her scores for "End-of-Course Examination Program" test results. There is a section "Algebra 1" and underneath a table with rows:

- Algebra
- Functions
- Numbers and Quantity; Interpreting Data

Can somebody explain and show examples of problems that belong to that "Numbers and Quantity; Interpreting Data" category?

Comment: In which country? The terminology might come from a national curriculum.

Comment: Sounds like statisitics and graphs

Comment: Search on the Common Core website (if it still exists).

Comment: Can you include what state you are in? If this is a public school, knowing the state will narrow this down immensely.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to look at her textbook.  If that does not make it clear, ask the teacher.  We can't guess what the words mean in the specific context of your sis's course.  It's not like there's only one right answer, one course.  And we have no idea what they were pushing in that specific course.